# How can I reload a php file with Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, text, external

I have a php file that's create a .txt file with name of some photos. But constantly new photos are being added to the images folder. On my index page, I have a javascript function that call the ajax function, because I don't want to reload the page. I just want to request again the php file to recreate the .txt file with the name of all photos again. Can someone help me with the ajax?

Comment: If you don't have any experience with ajax, I would recommend using a library like jQuery ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ for the even easier version ). Apart from that, I would use a database instead of text file.

Comment: Show what you have done so far. What problems did you encounter? What questions do you have exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I would use JQuery for this as it'll become much easier.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path/createtextfile.php',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('textfile created');
  }
});
```

As this stands right now it returns a result from createtextfile.php
and does a alert.

However if your file returns the names of all the pictures in a list (delimitered of course)

Example: `name1, name2, name3`

you can then explode this list into an array and use JQuery again to create html elements to display the names.